# upload image file to datastore using endpoints in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to make a form for adding users that will store user information to my database.

I want to upload an image file using Cloud Endpoints (python). I do not have any idea how to do it.

What will be the input class (request class) and output class (response class)?

```
@endpoints.method(inputclass, outputclass,
                      path='anypath', http_method='GET',
                      name='apiname')"
```

What url will I provide in the `action=` form field for uploading the image? How can I then show the file?

Comment: have you read any tutorials?

Comment: yes , i read a tutorial that upload a file using webapp2.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to store data files (include image file). 
The first one is to convert your image in base 64 format, and store it on datastore (Not the best).

The second one, is to store your image file in Google Cloud Storage (That is the best) or the blobstore (By Google themself, there is no good reason to use Blobstore).

So you have to store, your image file to Google Cloud Storage with your endpoint: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/?hl=fr

Personnaly, I use a servlet (App Engine) to store image in GCS. My endpoints call my servlet and pass image in parameter, and my servlet store image in GCS. It works very well =)

Hope I help you..